# Tell gerrit dependendies

Tags: git, merge, dependencies, gerrit

I submitted a change on gerrit and its status is now **"Submitted, Merge Pending"**.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell what other commits this merge is waiting for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737326/gerrit-change-has-statussubmitted-merge-pending-how-to-solve-it

Comment: @mkasberg Not really, that question already knows what the dependencies are, I don't. I'm not asking about how to fix it.

Comment: On the Gerrit web page for the problematic change, it should show "Related Changes". Changes that your change depends on are listed below your change here. Changes that depend on your change are listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mkasberg answered my question. Dependencies are shown in the 'Related Changes' section under the change you are on.

Answer (score 0):

You have committed some code that has also been worked on by another source. This has caused a maual merge to fail. You must locate the code and make a merge in your code so that it can be properly pushed up.